# How to access properties inside Listvew ItemsPanelTemplate and DataTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I'm quite new to c# and WPF. I'm making a small Photo Viewer. I want to have a grid of photos in which I can change the number of columns and the size of the pictures depending on user preferences and the size of the screen. I can do everything I need at design time but I don't find how to change some properties during runtime. 
In particular, I need to change the number of columns of the UniforGrid and the Width and Height of the Image.

```
<ListView x:Name="LVMiniaturasGrandes" Margin="23,10,464,270.5" Background="#FF272727" Foreground="White" Visibility="Hidden" BorderBrush="{x:Null}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <UniformGrid  Columns="4" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ItemsControl Padding="10">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                            <Image Source="{Binding ImagenGrande2}"  Width="200" Height="200" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" Stretch="Uniform" />
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding NombreFichero}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Foreground="White" />
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding VerEstrellas}" Foreground="Red" TextAlignment="Right" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ItemsControl>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

I expect to be able both to change the number of columns and the height and width of the Image(s) depending on a slider control position and the actual pixel size of the screen.

Any help is welcome. Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

I've been able to modify the number of columns in the UniformGrid. It may not be very elegant but it works. But I'm still not able to access the Width and Height of the Images.

```
private void RejillaImagenesGrandes_Initialized(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _UGImagenesGrandes = (UniformGrid)sender;
        }
```

This way I can get access to the UniformGrid and modify the number of columns dynamically

Comment: Have you tried using convertor or binding to slider length?

Comment: I need to do some Math to modify the width and height. I'm using, for the moment, a not very elegant approach binding the wdith and height to a field of the object to which the ItemsSorurce is bound. It works but seems quite strange to me. I will check how convertor works.

Comment: This is a simple converter tutorial to get started: https://www.wpf-tutorial.com/data-binding/value-conversion-with-ivalueconverter/